# How to fill width of form.well?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the example of my problem [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykCsA/1/)

```
<form class="well form-inline">
  <div class="input-append">
     <input type="text" class="input-block-level"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

A you can see search button gets out beyond the container. How can I resolve this without of setting fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used to `position`

```
    .input-append{position:relative;}
.input-block-level{position:relative;z-index:1;}
.add-on{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;z-index:2;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykCsA/3/)**

Comment: I need to set size of input 35px but I need to resize seatch button automaticaly: http://jsfiddle.net/ykCsA/6/

Comment: Now check to this demo http://jsfiddle.net/ykCsA/7/  Define this css .input-append  .add-on{height:auto;bottom:0;}